# Google sheets IF OR script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

So this is the code that I'm using for the script that I found;

```
function onOpen() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Todo');
  s.showRows(1, s.getMaxRows());

  s.getRange('D:D')
    .getValues()
    .forEach( function (r, i) {
    if (r[0] == 'X') 
      s.hideRows(i + 1);
    });
}
```

But I want it to hide the row if column D is X OR Y.  I am not a programmer, and I'm very new to this.  I have googled this to death but I'm not making any headway.  Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
if (r[0] == 'X')
```

to

```
if (r[0] == 'X' || r[0] == 'Y' )
```

Comment: That did it.  Thank you so much!